# Pandas Getting each business day of a year by using date range function

Tags: pandas, data-science, pandas-groupby, date-range, data-science-experience

I am trying to get all business day of a year by using pandas date_range function.But i am missing some necessary parameters to get my desired result.

```
pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='D')

DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-03', '2015-01-04',
               '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06', '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08',
               '2015-01-09', '2015-01-10',
               ...
               '2015-12-22', '2015-12-23', '2015-12-24', '2015-12-25',
               '2015-12-26', '2015-12-27', '2015-12-28', '2015-12-29',
               '2015-12-30', '2015-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=365, freq='D')
```

I am getting all days of that year which is not i want.

Comment: use freq parameter with 'B'

Answer (score 2):

Use the `freq` `B` for business days

```
pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq='B')

DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02', '2015-01-05', '2015-01-06',
               '2015-01-07', '2015-01-08', '2015-01-09', '2015-01-12',
               '2015-01-13', '2015-01-14',
               ...
               '2015-12-18', '2015-12-21', '2015-12-22', '2015-12-23',
               '2015-12-24', '2015-12-25', '2015-12-28', '2015-12-29',
               '2015-12-30', '2015-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=261, freq='B')
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared